# Конструкция prompt<>''

Tags: python

Вот проблема: скачал пакет livewires 2.1 с помощью pip, всё вроде установилось, но когда я пытаюсь импортировать его, вылезает исключение:

```
>>> from livewires import games
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    from livewires import games
  File "C:\Users\Мы\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-
packages\livewires\__init__.py", line 32, in <module>
    from beginners import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'beginners'
```

Лезу в файлы, понимаю, что файл 'beginners.py' лежит в той же папке, что и файл '**init**.py'. Полазил по Интернету, нашёл предположение, что файл 'beginners.py' написан на версии 2. Ок, думаю я, залезаю в файл 'beginners.py', начинаю исправлять код для версии 3. В конце концов я натыкаюсь на такую конструкцию:

```
...
if prompt<>'' and prompt[-1] not in string.whiteplace:
...
```

Что может значить prompt<>'' в версии 2?

Comment: не равно .......

Comment: @gil9red
Не равно чему?

Comment: пустой строке ..

Comment: Причина ModuleNotFoundError в том, что в Питоне 3 по умолчанию включена `from __future__ import absolute_import` директива. То есть в Питоне 3, следует писать `from .beginners import *` вместо `from beginners import *` здесь¶ Стоит найти именно Питон 3 версию нужного вам пакета, иначе даже если заработает код (без явных ошибок) нет гарантий, что те же результаты что и Питон 2 получите.

Answer (score 3):

`help('<>')` говорит, что `<>` оператор равнозначен `!=` оператору сравнения (неравенство) в Питоне 2. Даже в Питоне 2 это написание оператора было устаревшим:

```
$ python2 -mdis <<<'a<>b'
1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (a)
            3 LOAD_NAME                1 (b)
            6 COMPARE_OP               3 (!=)
            9 POP_TOP             
           10 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
           13 RETURN_VALUE
```

В Питоне 3, `<>` это синтаксическая ошибка.